# Password protection via .htaccess working in subdirectory but not in subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, password-protection

I have a main site and a subdomain test site. 
On the main site I have a folder previously used for testing...

/httpdocs/test/

Within that I have a htaccess file

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/myurl.com/private/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
Require valid-user
```

And an associated .htpasswd in the location specified. This works perfectly.
However, using exactly the same .htaccess for my new subdomain does not work
i.e. putting the .htaccess file at

/subdomains/tests/httpdocs/

or any subdirectory.

Any suggestions why this might be? I get the login screen but it won't accept any correct username/password.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Did you make sure to add an `Allow override` directive in your vhost definition?

Comment: It's an external server so I don't have access to many options. All I can really do is ftp .htaccess files. I can't (or at least I haven't found any way to) access httpd.conf. Is it likely that a default subdomain created though Plesk panel would default to disallow what I'm attempting?

Comment: Also, there are zero .htaccess files between /subdomains/tests/httpdocs/ and root.

Similarly, there are zero between /httpdocs/test/ and root. I would have thought the behaviour should be the same.